# Make a phoenix not attack when I move it to scout in starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

When I play PvZ, I often make hallucinated Phoenixes to scout. They have the ability to move and shoot which is great, but in this case I don't want them to shoot Overlords because it gives away they are fake.

I right click on the minimap (**not** attack move) yet they still attack any Overlords in their way for zero damage. I am almost thinking this is a bug, or maybe a strange behaviour of units that can attack and move.

Does anyone know how to move a Phoenix around to scout and not shoot an enemy?

Comment: I think that good zerg should not react to single phoenix at all if it hallucinated or not. If protoss going to starport one usually didn't show first phoenix to opponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that.

It is not a bug or strange behaviour.

It is one of the core features of the unit itself, they attack while moving. Their AI makes them attack even while they move, even for a hallucinated unit.

During the campaign, the diamondback unit also has this feature (attacking while moving).

Edit: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/phoenix

> The Phoenix can fire its weapons while moving, giving it a slight edge in tactical maneuverability.